# How to push to page when async function is finished?

Tags: flutter, dart

Im developing a app that when the user enters the first screen is a loading screen where initialize somethings from the Provider, the user cant input anything in this screen, when the loading finishes i want to push a new screen without the user "clicking" for it.

In this code, im actually given a delay of 3 seconds for the _login.getStoredEmail() to run and set a variable inside LoginController which in the next screen i consume, but of course this wont work everytime, eventually will break.

```
class GeneralSplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _GeneralSplashScreenState createState() => _GeneralSplashScreenState();
}

class _GeneralSplashScreenState extends State<GeneralSplashScreen> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    Future.delayed(
      Duration(
        seconds: 3,
      ),
      () {
        Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, kRoutes.login);
      },
    );
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final LoginController _login = Provider.of<LoginController>(context);

    _login.getStoredEmail();

    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 60),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[
            Image.asset(
              'lib/assets/images/logo.png',
              fit: BoxFit.contain,
            ),
            Text(
              "Business Mananger",
              textAlign: TextAlign.end,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontFamily: kFontFamily.montserrat,
                fontSize: 10,
              ),
            ),
            LoadingBar(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to a different screen inside the initState() method.

```
initState() {
  initializeAndNavigate()
}

initializeAndNavigate() async {
  await initializeSomething();
  Navigator.of(context) ...
}
```

Comment: Yeah i try that, but i cant get a provider instance in the init state.

Answer (score 0):

Declare `initState`

```
  Future _future;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    _future = doStuff();
  }
```

Use `FutureBuilder`

```
FutureBuilder(
      future: _future,
      builder: (_, dataSnapshot) {

        if (dataSnapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()); // here add loading screen
        } else {
          return Dashboard();
        }
      },
    )
```

Comment: I try that also, but when i use a FutureBuilder with a TextInput inside everytime i click the input it rebuilds the screen. The next screen is a login one. With two TextInputs.

Comment: @LucasCastelo: Added initState(), this should work in your case, as FutureBuilder will build only ones now

Comment: REALLY ? If i declare the function inside init state, and put that function in a FutureBuilder he wont rebuild ? WHAT ? This is game changer for me. Thanks. Im trying this.